# Use spring data repository instead of generated axon repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, axon

I built an application that uses CQRS using Spring boot and Axon framework. I want to use my own repository to persist entites in database instead of the axon repository. I tried to extract EventSourcingHandlers to another class and save here the entity and only let CommandHandlers aggregate class.

My problem is that when the command method is finished it calls the persist method from axon repository. Can I disable the axon call to the persist when command method is finished?

PS: I know this isn't the proper way of using axon but it's a workaround that I found

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question to me targets towards a State Store approach of an Aggregate instead of an Event Sourcing approach. This is perfectly doable within Axon Framework, also in a Spring Boot scenario.

You just have to mark the Aggregate as being an `@Entity` and add `@Id` to the `aggregateIdentifier` (or another field you'd like to be the id of course).
The Reference Guide also has a dedicated section to this, which you can find [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/command-handling/state-stored-aggregates).

The actual "persist" call you are referring to isn't logic of a `@CommandHandler` method, but is internal to the `AggregateLifecycle#apply(Object)` method.

Comment: Thank you for your response, is there a way to disable the persist call?

Comment: You can definitely get your way around it, although I would recommend against doing so. Maybe there's another way to solving your problem though. Do you mind elaborating _why_ you want to disable the persisting of your Aggregate, both in the state-stored and event-sourced scenario?